# Using EmguCV in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv

I'm trying to create a motion detection application using different libraries.

I have already implemented AForge library, now i'm a little stuck on EmguCV.

I'm having difficulties in understanding how to set up all the things.

If i understood correctly, in order to use EmguCV i must install OpenCV.

So i opened Nuget Package Manager in VS, found EmguCV ( first one in the list ) and installed. Version 3.0.0

**So my question is, which OpenCV version should i install?** Because EmguCV project page doesn't has no information on it, but OpenCV has many versions.

And additionaly, if someone knows some more computer vision libraries for C#, please write them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download and install the latest version of OpenCV from [here](http://opencv.org/). I have developed a gesture based sign language interpreter. Contour Analysis algorithm is good for object/pattern and motion detection.

Please read this article and also the code algorithm may help you.
[Contour Analysis](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C)

Answer (score 0):

I been using Emgu.Cv with WPF for some time now. They should be very similar just the calling methods will be different
Ex:
OpenCv = Cv2.imread
Emgu.Cv = CvInvoke.Imread

You can download both through the NuGet package manager
If you decide on Emgu download the one created by Emgu Corporation.